# What is the command to delete the rows where id is between 20 and 100 in the table Person?

Tags: mysql

What is the command to delete the rows where id is between 20 and 100 in the table Person?

I know BETWEEN is involved.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE id BETWEEN 20 AND 100
```

You were almost there! See the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).